# How can I change configuration for an existing vagrant box?

Tags: configuration, vagrant, virtual-machine

I have two installed vargrant boxes up and running. I want to change their configuration settings. Where can I do that? Specifically, I want to give each vagrant box some additional settings.

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.0.10"
config.vm.hostname = "alpha"
```

The above code is from this following question:
[Allow two or more vagrant VMs to communicate on their own network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867252/allow-two-or-more-vagrant-vms-to-communicate-on-their-own-network)

That code is normally put in the Vagrantfile. I want to make changes to an existing vagrant virtual machine. If I modify that machine's Vagrantfile, are the changes applied automatically, or do I need to do some other steps?

I just want to change the network and hostname settings on both virtual machines. I do not want to reinstall these virtual machines from scratch again. I do not want to have to redownload the base image for both virtual machines again.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the Vagrantfiles for both existing Vagrant boxes. Then I ran the command

```
vagrant up
```

Apparently, if a Vagrantfile has been changed since the last time a vagrant virtual machine was started, this command goes ahead and modifies the settings for that vagrant virtual machine. In my case, it added the networking settings successfully.